# How to handle locator's Dynamic ID in Cypress Automation Tool

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I am Facing issue during handling Dynamic ID's using Cypress Automation tool.I have given below Statement to check/tick Checkbox

```
 cy.get('#d6740015e413').click().debug()
```

**Got below error**

> "CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element:
>   '#d6740015e413', but never found it

."[image]

Can anyone Help to work with handling of handling ID's in cypress?

Comment: Have you read cypress documentation best practices? https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Selecting-Elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, since `ID's` are dynamically generated and cypress may not be able to find each time as it creates new one dynamically during each run.
Please try the below and see if cypress is able to perform click on checkbox?

```
cy.get('input[title="Development - Capitalized"]').click()
```

or

```
cy.get('td > input[title="Development - Capitalized"]').click()
```